# Detect "next" or "previous" button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, background-audio

Is there a way to handle the event of the user pressing Next or Previous on the media player controls that come down when the volume hardware buttons are pressed? Examples I've seen with the BackgroundAudioPlayer use songs that come with the XAP but I want to use the user's media library with the controls.

Is there a way to detect the next or previous event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible for you to detect that `Next` or `Previous` is pressed when the built-in media app (or any other 3rd party app that isn't your own) is in control of the audio.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you're looking for `SkipNext` and `SkipPrevious` which are [`UserAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.useraction%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)s.

There's a good sample that runs through a lot of this logic at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I've referenced the AudioPlayerAgent project but the UserAction event doesn't seem to be called.